Include c header file my header.h in main.cmm script of trace32
I need to include one c header file into .cmm script. This C header file contains an enum, with 100 enum variables- I need to declare all enum variables as cmm script variables. I want use those variables in cmm script.
my_header.h include-> in main.cmm and need to use enum variables-> in main.cmm script as a macro variable.
my_header.h has
enum week {
    Mon = 0,
    Tue = 1,
    Wed = 2
};

and I want to include that in my main.cmm as below:
&Mon=0
&Tue=1
&Wed=2

Note: I have tried with bellow code in main.cmm:
DO myheader.h

It is not leads to any error and also not include as macro of cmm script.

Once you loaded the debug symbols (usually .elf file) to PowerView, you have immediate access to the declared enums.
You can access the values using the Var.VALUE() function. E.g. in your example PRINT Var.VALUE(Mon).
If the enum is declared locally, you can use the full symbol path of the enum to access it. Use command sYmbol.List.Enum to see the symbol paths. Usage e.g. PRINT Var.VALUE(\\demo\main\Mon).
You can use Var.VALUE like other constants, macros or immediate values:
IF &result==Var.VALUE(\\demo\main\Mon)
  PRINT "Yes1"

In Var commands, you can access the enum immediately, as Var commands use a C expression parser:
Var.IF my_variable_today==Mon
  PRINT "Correct day"

Var.set my_variable_today=Tue

